# On coloring the faces of a surface differently with parameter-dependent colors

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Old versions of *Mathematica* (`$VersionNumber < 6`) supported [a particular syntax of `ParametricPlot3D[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/ParametricPlot3D) that allowed for graphics specifications to be supplied as the fourth component of a vector-valued function; e.g. `ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, v], g[u, v], h[u, v], Hue[w[u, v]]}, {u, umin, umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}]`.

Nowadays, this functionality has been superseded by the options `ColorFunction`, `PlotStyle`, and other related functions. Unfortunately, some flexibility seems to have been lost with these changes.

For instance, the old implementation of `ParametricPlot3D[]` allowed me to use `FaceForm[]` to color the two faces of a polygon differently, with the stuff within `FaceForm[]` depending on the parameters. This allowed me to do things like this:

```
<<Version5`Graphics` (* simulates old-school graphics *)

ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[u]) Cos[v], (3 + Cos[u]) Sin[v], Sin[u],
 {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[v, {0, Pi/2}]], 
  ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[v, {0, Pi/2}]]]}},
 {u, -7 Pi/6, 7 Pi/12}, {v, Pi/6, Pi/2},
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> False, PlotPoints -> 41]
```

[image: torus section with differently-colored faces]

Unfortunately, as can be seen through close inspection, I miss out on the adaptive plotting capability that is provided by the current implementation of `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

I know that in the current version, the output is a `GraphicsComplex[]` object, with the colors assigned through the option `VertexColors`, which doesn't interact at all with directives like `FaceForm[]`. It has been suggested to me that I do two plots with the different colorings, with one a perturbed version of the other, and then combining these two into one `Graphics3D[]` object. This seems rather wasteful to me, however.

In short: how can I do parameter-dependent coloring of a surface plotted with `ParametricPlot3D[]`, with the faces colored differently?

---

**(added 1/21/2011)**

Both of the answers given so far rely on the fact that color gradients in *Mathematica* can be turned into images that can subsequently be used as textures. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be applicable to general coloring schemes. Consider for instance the following twisted cylinders:

```
<<Version6`Graphics` (* restore default graphics *)

With[{a = 1, p = 2/3},
 GraphicsGrid[{
   {ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u] Cos[p Pi v] - a Sin[u] Sin[p Pi v], 
      a Cos[p Pi v] Sin[u] + a Cos[u] Sin[p Pi v], v},
     {u, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {v, -1, 1}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> (Hue[(1 - Cos[3 Pi #5] Sin[4 #4])/2] &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 85],

    ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u] Cos[p Pi v] - a Sin[u] Sin[p Pi v], 
      a Cos[p Pi v] Sin[u] + a Cos[u] Sin[p Pi v], v},
      {u, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {v, -1, 1}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> (Hue[(1 + Cos[3 #4] Cos[4 Pi #5])/2] &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 85]}
   }]]
```

[image: colored twisted cylinders]

where the cylinder on the left is colored with `Hue[(1 - Cos[3 Pi v] Sin[4 u])/2` and the one on the right is colored with `Hue[(1 + Cos[3 u] Cos[4 Pi v])/2]`. I want to be able to use something like `FaceForm[Hue[(1 + Cos[3 u] Cos[4 Pi v])/2], Hue[(1 - Cos[3 Pi v] Sin[4 u])/2]]`, as with the following image:

```
<< Version5`Graphics`

With[{a = 1, p = 2/3}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u] Cos[p Pi v] - a Sin[u] Sin[p Pi v], 
   a Cos[p Pi v] Sin[u] + a Cos[u] Sin[p Pi v], v, {EdgeForm[],
   FaceForm[Hue[(1 + Cos[3 u] Cos[4 Pi v])/2],
            Hue[(1 - Cos[3 Pi v] Sin[4 u])/2]]}},
  {u, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {v, -1, 1},
   Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> False, PlotPoints -> 85]]
```

[image: two-faced colored cylinder]

and it looks to me that the current solutions don't apply to this situation. What can be done here?

Comment: I love the questions people are coming up with.  J. M. I am curious: did you feel this question was inappropriate for SO?

Comment: I thought it was too simple, since it was simple to do in old versions of *Mathematica*...

Comment: Concerning the addition, Vitaliy's second solution would work, i.e. plotting the function twice and overlaying them. Just use a different a `ColorFunction` for each plot.

Comment: Still seems like a bit of a waste of effort to me, @Heike. The actual functions I'm dealing with can take a long time to evaluate...

Answer (score 16):

My friend C.H. enlightened me, that in current version of M. ColorFunction defines vertex colors which in turn define polygon colors. Because vertexes cannot have 2 different colors for different sides of a surface, so can’t polygons.

I will show two solutions.

**So here is one solution.** We can extract images from ColorData:

[image]

and just use textures - if you want to call ParametricPlot3D only once. You can easily map different textures on different sides of a surface, use Specularity and Opacity with them.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] (3 + Cos[v]), Sin[u] (3 + Cos[v]), 
  Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 1.5}, {v, -3.5, 2}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Specularity[White, 50], 
   FaceForm[Texture[ColorData["BrightBands", "Image"]], 
    Texture[ColorData["DarkRainbow", "Image"]]]], Axes -> False, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

---

**Another solution**, as you mentioned, is to put 2 surfaces together. I really like it, it's light and zippy. I will mention it here for completeness of example. In M. we can make surface (its polygons) to be transparent if you look from one side and colored from the other with help of `FaceForm[None , {}]`. Clearly demonstrated below with Möbius strip:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
  r Sin[t/2]}, {r, -1.5, 1.5}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {10, 60}, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None, Orange], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

You can also do things like `PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None, Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]]]` We will uses this. Each graphics one surface’s side is effectively turned off, so shifting the two surfaces with respect to each other is not needed.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
   Sin[v]}, {v, -Pi/1, Pi/1.5}, {u, 0, Pi/1.5}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#5] &), 
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[{}, None] ],

 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
   Sin[v]}, {v, -Pi/1, Pi/1.5}, {u, 0, Pi/1.5}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BrightBands"][#5] &), 
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None, {}] ]
]
```

[image]

======================== **Reply to 1st Comment** ========================

Trimming anyhow color maps will work:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] (3 + Cos[v]), Sin[u] (3 + Cos[v]), 
  Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 1.5}, {v, -3.5, 2}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Specularity[White, 50], 
   FaceForm[
    Texture[ImageTake[
      ColorData["BrightBands", "Image"], {0, 31}, {85, 250}]], 
    Texture[ImageTake[
      ColorData["DarkRainbow", "Image"], {0, 31}, {85, 250}]]]], 
 Axes -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: In your first snippet, I note that you mapped the entire gradient set on different faces. But, what if I only wanted a section of the gradient, like in the image in my question?

Comment: @J.M. I posted a reply at the end of my answer.

Comment: I managed to figure out my own solution. :) Thanks for the starting idea!

Comment: It is really not intuitive that a polygon can be transparent from one side and opaque from the other.  This was the highlight of the answer for me.  You should make this point a lot more visible in the long answer!

Comment: I edited your answer to make it easier to skim through, and still notice the important points.  Please review the edit and make sure I didn't change anything you don't want changed!

Comment: You can just [click here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/411/revisions) to see what I changed

Comment: There is in fact an example of a plot with an opaque face and a translucent face in [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FaceForm.html#37709688).

Comment: @Szabolcs I think you are right - I updated the answer. Let me know if you have other suggestions. You can proof-read text if you wish.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not read your reply in detail the first time I saw it.  I thought you just used two textures.  I only noticed this great (and to me--surprising) possibility of `FaceForm[{}, None]` today.  I don't dare proofread ... I'm not a native English speaker and unlike you, I have never lived in an English speaking country ...

Answer (score 11):

I managed to answer my own clarificatory question to Vitaliy. The idea, in addition to giving `ColorData[]` as a `Texture[]` (not too straightforward for me, but whatever) is to modify the options `TextureCoordinateFunction` and `TextureCoordinateScaling`.

For the example I gave in my question, the old syntax would have looked like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[u])*Cos[v], (3 + Cos[u])*Sin[v], Sin[u], 
   {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[v, {0, Pi/2}]], 
     ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[v, {0, Pi/2}]]]}},
   {u, -7*(Pi/6), 7*(Pi/12)}, {v, Pi/6, Pi/2}]
```

Here's how to use Vitaliy's idea along with modifications to `TextureCoordinateFunction` and `TextureCoordinateScaling`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[u])*Cos[v], (3 + Cos[u])*Sin[v], Sin[u]},
               {u, -7*(Pi/6), 7*(Pi/12)}, {v, Pi/6, Pi/2}, Mesh -> False,
               PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Texture[ColorData["DarkRainbow", "Image"]], 
                                    Texture[ColorData["BrightBands", "Image"]]],
               TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({Rescale[#5, {0, Pi/2}], #4} & ),
               TextureCoordinateScaling -> {True, True, True, True, False}]
```

Compare:

[image: torus section with differently colored faces]

Answer (score 9):

This solution is basically a combination of Vitaliy's solutions. It uses two plots plotted on top of each other using `Show` but the 3D surface is calculated for only once so it shouldn't take much longer than using `FaceForm[]` directives as in older versions of *Mathematica*.

First we plot two 2D images of the pattern we want to use for the fronts and back of the final plot. Suppose that the `ColorFunction` specifications we want to use are

```
colf1[u_, v_] := GrayLevel[(1 - Cos[3 Pi v] Sin[4 u])/2];
colf2[u_, v_] := Hue[(1 + Cos[3 u] Cos[4 Pi v])/2];
```

To create the patterns we use `RegionPlot`

```
{tex1, tex2} = Image[RegionPlot[True, {u, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {v, -1, 1},
     ColorFunction -> Function[{u, v}, #[u, v]],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     PlotRangePadding -> 0,
     Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 80, 
     BoundaryStyle -> None]] & /@ {colf1, colf2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At this point I tried using one of Vitaliy's solutions and plot the 3D surface with `TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)` and `PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Texture[tex1], Texture[tex2]]]`. This did produce a plot in the end but it took a lot of time and memory, so instead we're using separate plots for the front and back. First the front:

```
front = With[{a = 1, p = 2/3},
   ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u] Cos[p Pi v] - a Sin[u] Sin[p Pi v], 
       a Cos[p Pi v] Sin[u] + a Cos[u] Sin[p Pi v], v}, 
     {u, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {v, -1, 1}, 
     Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> False,
     PlotPoints -> 15, 
     Lighting -> "Neutral",
     TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &),
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[tex1], FaceForm[{}, None]]
   ]];
```

Instead of plotting the same function again for the back, we're using replacement rules to replace the `Texture` and `FaceForm` of the front

```
back = front /. 
  {Texture[a_] :> Texture[tex2], FaceForm[{}, None] :> FaceForm[None, {}]};
Show[front, back]
```

which gives the following result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The advantage of using `Texture` over `ColorFunction` is that we can make do with much fewer `PlotPoints` for the 3D image when we use `Texture` (15 vs 80 in this case) to still have a satisfying result, so although we are still plotting every polygon twice, the total number of polygons in the end result is still less than if we had used the pre-version 6 method.

The disadvantage of this method is that it only works for patterns that depend on the free parameters of the surface only and not on the spatial coordinates.