# Fit text to a path

Tags: graphics, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Movable text on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/movable-text-on-a-curve)

This is a common feature among vector-based graphics suites (e.g. Illustrator), so I was wondering how it could be done in Mathematica. Here's an example:

[image]

I'm pretty sure one has to "vectorize the font" first, as demonstrated [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html) under "neat examples," but beyond that, I'm stuck. In Illustrator, one can choose to align the text to the path using the baseline, ascenders, descenders, and also choose various methods of fitting the path to the curve ("rainbow," "skew," "3D ribbon," "stair step," "gravity"), but I would be satisfied with a solution that uses the lowest point in a string of text (i.e. the descender), and uses the "rainbow" style of Illustrator, as is shown in the above example.

For simplicity, let's just align the above string ("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog") with the Sin function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16194/5

Comment: OK, I am comfortable with closing my question as neither Google nor the in-site search could match "fit text to a path" with this question, which is what it is commonly referred to in Illustrator. The answer does appear to be there.

Comment: Thanks. Now with this question, there will be a search match on Google for "fit text to a path" :)

Comment: Couple more related questions (for ideas and inspirations): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719/5 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5783/5