# How to draw formatted text on a surface such as a sphere?

Tags: graphics

Using Mathematica 9, I would like to write text over a surface, for example a sphere. Something like this:

[image]

I tried the code available [here in MSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/rotating-an-image-along-a-m%C3%B6bius-strip) but the output is not so beautiful like shown.

I would like to setup, if possible, font, size, color, bold/italics/stroke, etc.

Engraving or embossing the text would be a very nice bonus:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: i 've tried this:

text = Style["Hello!", 200];
R := 4;
ParametricPlot3D[{R Sin[u] Cos[v],R s Sin[u]   Sin[v], R Cos[u],, , {u, 0, Pi},
{v, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Texture[text]], Opacity[.5]}, 
TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)]

Comment: Why not just do this in free 3D software like blender, then bring that model into Mathematica if you have to? Mathematica's own CSG operations like RegionUnion / RegionIntersection etc which you might consider for the engraving, are somewhat bug prone and difficult to use. The texture wrapping would be much easier in blender too. This question also seems subjective as it's not clear what you mean by _not so beautiful_.

Comment: @flinty, i would like to stay with Mathematica and see its power of expression.  also learning new software for every different task will decrease my chances to become a Mathematica proficient user. and making such demands may also serve as a  stimulus for Mathematica programmers to improve the software.

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi then perhaps a valuable lesson to learn about Mathematica is how to call into external libraries, or import data from external software. It would be unreasonable to expect Mathematica to be the perfect tool for the job in every case, which it is not, and being aware of its limitations may help you out more in the long run.

Answer (score 12):

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"
> ```

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["hello", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text]
```

[image]

```
linecoords = (MeshPrimitives[bdg, 1, Multicells -> True] /. 
   Line[x_] :> Line[Join @@ x])[[All, 1]];


{xminmax, yminmax} = MinMax /@ Transpose[Join @@ linecoords];

rsT[newRanges_ : {{-Pi/4, Pi/4}, {-1/4, 1/4}}] := 
  RescalingTransform[{xminmax, yminmax}, newRanges];

spCoords = {Cos[#] Sin[ArcCos @ #2], Sin[#] Sin[ArcCos @ #2], #2} & @@@ 
 rsT[][#] & /@ linecoords;

Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], White, Tube[#, .02] & /@ spCoords, 
   MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Sphere[]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

```
spCoords = {Cos[#] Sin[ArcCos@#2], Sin[#] Sin[ArcCos@#2], #2} & @@@ 
    rsT[{{-Pi/3, Pi/2}, {-1/3, 1/3}}][#] & /@ linecoords; 

 Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], White, Tube[#, .03] & /@ spCoords, 
    MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Sphere[]},
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

For another example, take the surface produced by `Plot3D`:

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 Sin[x + y^2];

plot3D = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle ->  MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}],
   Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotRange -> All, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];

surfaceCoords = ({#, #2, f[#, #2]} & @@@ 
   RescalingTransform[{xminmax, yminmax}, {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-1, 1}}]@#) & /@ 
  linecoords;

 Show[plot3D, 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], White, Tube[#, .05] & /@ surfaceCoords}], 
 ViewPoint -> {-0.5, -2, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have mathematica 9, and the suggested code do not compile. for the hello example, yhe first error message is:

Part::partd: 
(((("\"Part specification \!\(\(MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[\*InterpretationBox[Cell[BoxData[\nFormBox[\nStyleBox[\\\"\\\\<\\\\\\\"hello\\\\\\\"\\\\>\\\",\nStripOnInput->False,\nFontFamily->\\\"Cambria\\\"], TextForm]], \\\"InlineText\\\"],\nText[Style[" hello) ", FontFamily -> ") Cambria) "]]], _Text], 1, Multicells -> True]\)[[All, 1]]\) is longer than depth of object\"")

Comment: for the plot3d example, the first of many errors messages is:
escalingTransform::inpf: {xminmax,yminmax} is not a list of length 2 vectors

Comment: this code bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["hello", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text]
 does not produce any ouput in Mathemtica 9

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi, I added info on the version/os I am using.

Comment: pity the code does not work in Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 2):

This won't get you the embossing, but you can just use Texture:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[v] Cos[u], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[
      Texture[
        ImageReflect[
          ImagePad[
            Rasterize[
              Style["sphere", FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Marker Felt"]], {{800, 0}, {200, 100}}, White],
          Top]]]]
```

[image]

We re-orient the rasterized image with ImageReflect so that it reads as expected. ImagePad is just an easy way to push the text around the surface to where you want it.

Comment: i1ve tested your code in mathematica 9 and the text is not rendered only the sphewre sppears.

Answer (score 1):

adapted from a chatGPT suggestion:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[v] Cos[u], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 
      2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> 
      Directive[
       Texture[ImageReflect[
         ImagePad[
          Rasterize[
           Graphics[
            Text[Style["sphere", FontSize -> 50, 
              FontFamily -> "Marker Felt"], 
             Background -> LightBlue]]], {{800, 0}, {200, 100}}, 
          LightBlue], Top]]], TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), 
     Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

output:

[image]

however i don't know how to rewrite the code in order to gave a gradient color over the sphere.

Comment: Please provide the image that this code produces.

Comment: @ 
bbgodfrey
, done!

Comment: The code does not work, missing some `[`

Comment: @cvgmt, i've updated the code, please, see if this works now!